# How to evaluate the model performance under multiclass random forest fitting?

Tags: classification, python, random-forest, model-evaluation, multi-class

I just use the code to run random forest for multiclass response. I binarize the output to apply the ROC score for model performance. Could someone can advice other methods for the performance validation? cheers

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,oob_score=True,class_weight  = 'balanced') 

results=rf.fit(X_train,np.ravel(y_train)) 

roc_auc_score(y_test,results.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
```

Comment: multi-class ROC AUC is not a well-specified problem. some discussion here: http://people.inf.elte.hu/kiss/11dwhdm/roc.pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004172/precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification